# Searching all the combinations using R

Tags: r

I have 5 Lists as shown below columns -

```
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
AR1 AW1 AD2 AA1 AX1
AR2 AW2 AD4 AA2 AX3
AR3 AW3 AD5 AA3 AX5
    AW4 AD6 AA4 AX7
        AD7 AA7 AX8
        AD9 AA8 
            AA9
```

Not sure if formatting is diplayed exactly, so Column c1 contains letters AR1,AR2,AR3 while Column c2 contains AW1, AW2,AW3, AW4 and so on for c3, c4 & c5

I want to derive all the possible combinations from these 5 columns e.g. AR1 AW2 AD2 AA1 AX3 and so on. Is there a way to derive these using R?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
res <- expand.grid(lapply(df1, function(x) x[x!='']))
```